# How do I send a single html form to OneSignal server and another Server

Tags: javascript, php, onesignal

I have a form that requires to be sent to OneSignal and then to a mySql db on another server

```
<form action="AppPushUserOne.php" method="post">
    <textarea class="form-control" id="Message" name="Message" rows="5" placeholder ="Please insert your Incident and Deployment location here..."></textarea>
    <br>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block">Send Push Notification Message</button>
    <button onclick="postTimeEvent();" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block">Send DB</button>
</form>
```

The Submit button goes to OneSignal and the second button goes to a mySql db on another server.  How would I combine those two buttons?  I do not think it is wise to add type="submit" and onclick="postTimeEvent(); to the same button.

php I am using

```
    <?php                           
        function sendMessage($message){

            $content = array(
                "en" => $message
            );

            $headings = array(
                "en" => 'Pembina User here'
            );

            $fields = array(
                'app_id' => "be8a65fa-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx",
                'ios_badgeType' => 'SetTo',
                'ios_badgeCount' => '1',
                'included_segments' => array('All'),
                'headings' => $headings,
                'contents' => $content
            );

            $fields = json_encode($fields);

            print("\nJSON sent:\n");
            print($fields);

            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://onesignal.com/api/v1/notifications");
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
                    'Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    'Authorization: Basic xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
                )
            );
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);

            $response = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);

            return $response; 
        }

        $response = sendMessage($_POST['Message']);

        $return["allresponses"] = $response;
        $return = json_encode( $return);

        print("\n\nJSON received:\n");
        print($return);
        print("\n");
    ?>
```

js form I am using

```
    <script>
        function postTimeEvent() {
            var event_log = document.getElementById("Message").value;
            var dataString = 'event_log1=' + event_log;
            if (event_log == '')
            {
                alert("Please Fill All Fields");
            }
            else
            {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "ajax.php",
                    data: dataString,
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(html) {
                        alert(html);
                    }
                });
            }
            return false;
        }       
    </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally, your PHP code in `AppPushUserOne.php` should be taking care of sending the same message to your MySQL DB. You can do this by simply appending the code from your `ajax.php` file to `AppPushUserOne.php`, or you may use `curl` to `POST` the data to `ajax.php` once you are done sending it to OneSignal.

However, if you wish to do it via JavaScript, you will have to call the `postTimeEvent()` function before the form is submitted, otherwise the AJAX call to `ajax.php` might not get triggered. To do this, give an `id` to your `form` (e.g. `myForm`), set `type="button"` for your button, and once the AJAX call is successful, `submit` your form.

```
<form id="myForm" action="AppPushUserOne.php" method="post">
    <textarea class="form-control" id="Message" name="Message" rows="5" placeholder ="Please insert your Incident and Deployment location here..."></textarea>
    <br>
    <button type="button" onclick="postTimeEvent();" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block">Send Push Notification Message and Send to DB</button>
</form>

<script>
    function postTimeEvent() {
        var event_log = document.getElementById("Message").value;
        var dataString = 'event_log1=' + event_log;
        if (event_log == '')
        {
            alert("Please Fill All Fields");
        }
        else
        {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "ajax.php",
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,
                success: function(html) {
                    alert(html);
                    $('#myForm').submit();
                }
            });
        }
        //return false;
    }       
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you, I have tried to use the php to insert into the MySQL DB.  The issue I had was I could never really get the php to insert with the message and not when page opens.  That is why i went the .JS route.